# Storing instance of a Class in a Rails session causes TypeError exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In our Rails application we want to store an instance of a class in a session. This is because we want to set the class with some parameters when the user first logs into the application and then re-use this class by pulling it back out of the same session. When their session expires or they log out, this instance of the class is destroyed.

We're doing this to avoid using a Singleton class because that would live at Application-level and be available on different processes and stick around longer than the user's session, and have security implications due to it also being available to other users who haven't created a session yet.

So this is how it works:

```
session[:example_class] = ExampleClass.new(field_one: 'field_one', field_two: 'field_two')
```

This works fine!

However if I then do this:

```
current_instance = session[:example_class]
current_instance.do_something
session[:example_class] = current_instance
```

Whereby I am calling a method on this instance or whatever and then want to push that updated instance back into the session again so it's stored somewhere... we get this error:

```
TypeError in HomeController#index

ExampleClass can't be referred to from /Users/cameron/.rbenv/versions/2.5.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/bundler/gems/activerecord-session_store-376ed7f7aba1/lib/active_record/session_store.rb:64:in `dump'
```

And that method that is failing in `session_store.rb` is:

```
def self.dump(value)
  ::Base64.encode64(Marshal.dump(value))
end
```

And the `value` it's trying to store is:

```
{"_csrf_token"=>"nrw4m2ZAECwD3TiaPZoaSt4vL1DvjO+COnBpUQGwpXs=", "example_class"=>#<ExampleClass:0x00007f7fa7b1b998 @field_one="field_one", @field_two="field_two">}
```

Why can I write the class in the first time around... but afterwards it throws that error?

And how we get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have an answer for why the above error happened but it turns out if you're storing an instance of a class inside the session, you're in fact storing the instance and not just the current state of the class as I originally thought it was doing.

This basically means that whenever you interact with that class and change it's attributes the session is still reading from the same instance you are interacting with and therefore has the same information without having to write back into the session.

In short you have the behaviour of a Singleton class but using a session to maintain state.

Comment: One thing to bear in mind is that Rails by default uses [CookieStore](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Session/CookieStore.html) with a 4k limit imposed by the browser. I would really consider using memcached or redis for this instead.

Comment: It’s only tiny what we’re storing. But our sessions are also stored in the database via session store active record.

Answer (score 3):

I can't answer you fully why it fails, but I wouln't rely on implicit serialization of Ruby objects.

I would find a way to serialize the object of `ExampleClass` explicitly (similar to `as_json`) - convert to a hash, then store the hash in the session. When you need this object again, initialize `ExampleClass` instance with the params from session and then serialize it back to session.